# Is there a keyword to identify a PRIMARY column in a MySQL WHERE clause?

Tags: mysql, sql, primary-key, where-clause

I have a situation where the column name "field1" and "field3" are not given to me but all the other data is.  The request is coming in via a url in like: /table1/1 or /table2/3 and it is assumed that 1 or 3 represent the primary key. However, the column name may be different.  Consider the following 2 queries:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 where field1 = 1 and field2 =2;
SELECT * FROM table2 where field3 = 3 and field4 =4;
```

Ideally, I'd like to perform a search like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 where MYSQL_PRIMARY_COLUMN = 1 and field2 =2;
SELECT * FROM table2 where MYSQL_PRIMARY_COLUMN = 3 and field4 =4;
```

Is there a keyword to identify MYSQL_PRIMARY_COLUMN  in a MySQL WHERE clause?

Comment: How could you **not** be given the "primary key" column? Sounds like a very strange environment. The only thing I can think of: you need to query the `information_schema` and retrieve the PK columns for the table from there. But honestly: you should try to rethink your process there.

Comment: "SHOW INDEX FROM myTable": This does the job as a standalone command. Did you absolutely need it inside another query? It's really hard to know what you're trying to do if you only give us non-significant names like table1 and field1.

Comment: The request is coming in via a url in like:  /table1/1  or /table2/3  and it is assumed that 1 or 3 represent the primary key.  However, the column name may be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no pseudocolumn you can use to map to the primary key column.  One reason this is complicated is that a given table may have a multi-column primary key.  This is a totally ordinary way to design a table:

```
CREATE TABLE BooksAuthors (
  book_id INT NOT NULL,
  author_id INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (book_id, author_id)
);
```

When I implemented the table data gateway class in Zend Framework 1.0, I had to write code to "discover" the table's primary key column (or columns) as @doublesharp describes.  Then the table object instance retained this information so that searches and updates knew which column (or columns) to use when generating queries.

I understand you're looking for a solution that doesn't require this "2 pass process" but no such solution exists for the general case.

Some application framework environments attempt to simplify the problem by encouraging developers to give every table a single column primary key, and name the column "id" by convention.  But this convention is an oversimplification that fails to cover many legitimate table designs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`DESCRIBE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain.html) (which is a synonym for [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain.html)) to get information about the table, which will include the all column information.

```
DESCRIBE `table`;
```

You can also use [`SHOW INDEX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-index.html) to just get information about the `PRIMARY` key.

```
SHOW INDEX FROM `table` WHERE Key_name = 'PRIMARY'
```

Comment: Thanks for the response doublesharp.  in my case I need to *use* the column vs. looking it up.  I suppose I could use the results in my where clause, but I'd like to avoid a 2 pass process for the lookup.

Comment: Look it up once, then you know what it is... if the PRIMARY key is changing then you are going to have lots of other issues.